# Synthesizer resources

Tags: midi, hardware, synthesizer, music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to learn how to make electronic music. Where do I start?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/i-want-to-learn-how-to-make-electronic-music-where-do-i-start)

I'm interested in starting making electronic music. My problem is I have no clue where to start.

I know little about synthesizers in general, where can I find some guides/tutorials of how they work and so on.

Second, what should I look(hear) for when trying/buying equipment? (One alternative is a midi-keyboard and plugging it into the computer, but don't know what i miss except the hardware buttons and the "instruments own sound" so to say)

What effects/hardware buttons are good to have?

I'm interested in music/sounds similar to c64,hardstyle,dubstep,electroica,trance,EBM.

Comment: Since I think your real goal is to to get started in electronic music, I'd like to suggest [this question which had a pretty great answer](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/i-want-to-learn-how-to-make-electronic-music-where-do-i-start).

Comment: You don't miss anything with the alternative (MIDI keyboard and Softwares synths). Nowadays MIDI keyboards usually have additional assignable knobs or faders (even drum pads sometime). But in this case you also need an ASIO sound card for low latency, otherwise it's impossible to play...

Comment: @az01, thanks for the answer, then I will probably go for a MIDI-setup. (And maybe later get a hardware synth, when I have the need for mobility or want an analog one)

Answer (score 2):

Sound On Sound's *[Synth Secrets](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/allsynthsecrets.htm/)* series is a goldmine of info about synthesizers.

> My problem is I have no clue where to start.

Start by talking to people. In person if you can, or in forums. Try to avoid buying stuff right away. Use free software like Audacity and Pure Data as well as the demo modes of the various commercial DAWs and synths.

This is a big question, and probably better served by a community wiki or some other general purpose resource.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I know it's a big question but couldn't find any related question here and I think it's a valid one since as a beginner you don't know what resources are good or accurate.

Comment: It isn't a good question. According to the [FAQ](http://avp.stackexchange.com/faq): _You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page_.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, but it's hard to ask a specific question if you have no idea what to ask for.

Comment: @Vixen It's too broad to get really good specific answers (it's really a collection of smaller questions of varying focus) but the basic intention is good and I think with some research and focus it can be a great question. Drop me an @ reply in chat anytime and I'd be happy to help you out.